# How to process a file in php received through server routing?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, less

I am trying to route all my `.less` files to a php file to be processed.
The php file gets the `.less` file url and return processed `text/css`.

I have this line in my `.htacces` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  (\.less)$
RewriteRule (.*)  renderless.php?url=$1 [QSA]

</IfModule>
```

The above works as expected and routes the `.less` file to the php.

I'm using this line to get the url in the php ([heres the full code](https://gist.github.com/hitautodestruct/eff8a9619d4ba6969aa2)):

```
$file = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . $_GET['url'];

// .. some lines later

$css = file_get_contents( $file );
```

**But!** The php throws an error because it can't find the less file:

```
load error: failed to find local.mysite.com/css/main.less' in ...
```

If I manually send in a path the php processor works.

- Am I doing something wrong in the `htaccess` file?
- Is the issue in the php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `http://` here:

```
$file = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . $_GET['url'];
```

OR else read it from filesystem:

```
$file = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/' . $_GET["url"];
```

btw your rewrite rule can be much simpler also:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.less)$ /renderless.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I'm getting an error from that rewrite rule.. `Object not found!`

Comment: Hmm not sure if anything is wrong try: `RewriteRule ^(.+?\.less)$ renderless.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Just copy pasted. Rewrite rule works but the php is still throwing an error with the `http://`

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you try **`$file = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/' . $_GET["url"];`**

Comment: YES! Working now! Thanks so much.